# Puppet: file_line evaluates os.path.join

Tags: mysql, regex, django, puppet

I'm trying to replace the Django-Settings line

`'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3'),`

by

`'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.mysql'),`

but it doesn't find it.

The other line with the ENGINE parameter works fine. The problem must be the "os.path.join"-part.

```
  # replace sqlite3 db with mysql
    file { '/var/www/mysite/mysite/settings.py':
      ensure => present,
    }
    file_line { 'replace db engine':
      path                => '/var/www/mysite/mysite/settings.py',
      replace             => true,
      line                => "'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',",
      match               => "'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',",
      append_on_no_match  => false,
    }

    file_line { 'replace db name':
      path                => '/var/www/mysite/mysite/settings.py',
      replace             => true,
      line                => "\'NAME\': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , \'db.mysql\'),",
      match               => "\'NAME\': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , \'db.sqlite3\'),",
      append_on_no_match  => false,
    }
```

I tried it with \' and without \ .

Can somebody please help?

EDIT:
So if I add something like this beforehand:

```
  class { '::mysql::server':
    root_password    => 'strongpassword',
    override_options => { 'mysqld' => { 'max_connections' => '1024' } }
  }

  mysql::db { 'mynewDB':
    user     => 'admin',
    password => 'secret',
    host     => 'master.puppetlabs.vm',
    sql        => '/tmp/states.sql',
    require => File['/tmp/states.sql'],
  }
```

Then I would replace the NAME parameter with "mynewDB"?
Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `db.mysql` would not be a file; MySQL does not use a file to store its data, unlike sqlite. This doesn't seem like a thing you would want to do. In any case, you should structure your settings files better in the first place to take environment-specific data like this from env vars, rather than getting Puppet to replace lines.

Comment: Hello, thank you for clarifying this. I'm new to django and puppet, but have to learn how to set MySQL as the default database in Django. I thought, it would be simply replacing sqlite3 with mysql.. Is there any name or other parameters that must be set? I was reading this (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database). The part where the settings.py is modified for mysql is simply shown with "Engine" and "options". In any case I would need to replace the "name" line, right?

Comment: No, you need to set the NAME to the actual name of your database in MySQL, which has nothing to do with a file name. Did you create a database? For some reason that tutorial has put the name/user/password in a separate file which is read in, which is a bit odd, but never mind; if you're doing that you don't want NAME here at all. I would rather specify those parameters directly in settings though.

Comment: I edited the post - could you tell me please, if I understood you correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bear in mind that the `match` parameter to a `file_line` resource conveys a *regular expression*, not a plain string.  Puppet uses the Ruby flavor of regular expressions.  In that dialect, like in many others, the parentheses (`()`) are metacharacters, signifying grouping.  You must escape them if you want them to be interpreted as literals.  Moreover, because Ruby regexes use the same escape character that Puppet strings do, you must also escape the escape character to pass it through Puppet to the underlying regex engine.  On the other hand, you do not need to escape single quotes inside a double-quoted string, or vise versa, though doing so should not be harmful.

Example:

```
file_line { 'replace db name':
  path                => '/var/www/mysite/mysite/settings.py',
  replace             => true,
  line                => "'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.mysql'),",
  match               => "'NAME': os.path.join\\(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3'\\),",
  append_on_no_match  => false,
}
```

But that's a bit of a poor design.  If you're trying to ensure that the database you want is properly named (regardless of what the actual name should be), then to the greatest degree possible, you should match the line you want to manage in a way that does not depend on the current database name.

I'm not knowledgeable about Django specifics, but if you can rely on only one `NAME` property being specified in the settings file then you might instead do this:

```
file_line { 'replace db name':
  path                => '/var/www/mysite/mysite/settings.py',
  replace             => true,
  line                => 'Whatever the line should really be',
  match               => "\\s*'NAME':.*",
  append_on_no_match  => false,
}
```

The match expression there matches a line with an arbitrary amount of leading whitespace, followed by the literal characters `'NAME':`, followed by *anything*.

But you should also consider whether `file_line` is the right tool for the job at all.  It really makes sense only if you need to accommodate some parts of the file being managed outside Puppet, which is an uncomfortable situation, albeit one that sometimes we are stuck with.  If possible, though, it is better to allow Puppet to manage the entire file, including its complete contents.

Comment: Thank you very much! This explanation is great!